# How to auto update canvas screen via ajax every X seconds?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, canvas

I have a task to create social network

I have a home page that displays all drawings created by users via canvas. Users can draw on their own drawing and can add **contributors** which have righ to draw on their drawing also. The thing is they can both draw in the same time somehow.

The thing i want to do is, that when one user draws the canvas image, it is updating for other user who is watching that same drawing without refreshing the page.

I want to note that program works well, the only problem is that you have to refresh the page to see changes of drawing

Here is my client side code where i add previously drawed picture to empty canvas before new drawing

```
canvas = document.getElementById('can');

contain = document.getElementById('contain');
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.src = ''+drugi+'/'+prvi+'.png';
imageObj.onload = function() {
ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
};
```

Here is the request to ajax to save drawing after every start of the draw() function (which is everytime you move your mouse while drawing on canvas)

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);
ctx.strokeStyle = x;
ctx.lineWidth = y;
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open("POST",'saveimg.php',false);
ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/upload');
ajax.send(dataURL );
```

This is server side code

```
<?php
 session_start();
 $crtez = $_SESSION['tmpdrawing'];
 $kategorija = $_SESSION['tmpkat'];
 if (isset($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]))
 {
 $imageData=$GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'];
 $filteredData=substr($imageData, strpos($imageData, ",")+1);
 $unencodedData=base64_decode($filteredData);
 $fp = fopen($kategorija . '/' . $crtez . '.png', 'wb' );
 fwrite( $fp, $unencodedData);
 fclose( $fp );
?>
```

Now when we have a code, actual thing i want is the first code, which changes canvas appearance to be launched for example in every 3 seconds, so the other users currently on that drawing can see the picture updating without refreshing page.

If you need more code in client side i will post.

**I want to say again that the program works perfectyl, the only thing i need to finish it is auto updating canvas via ajax**

Comment: Put the ajax function inside [**setInterval**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval) maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should wrap javascript code into function and than just call that function when something is changed on the server side. As I know, there are two concepts for communitaion between clients and server:

1. Server Pooling - using javascript, client sends a HTTP request every X seconds and do something when server send some updates, for example update canvas. This is an "old school" and performance-poor pattern, maybe you should avoid it. If you like The Simpsons, this is it: [Are we there yet](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=adGs-RGss6Y) Take a look:  [Server Pooling Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835835/jquery-simple-polling-example)
2. Web Socket Communication - full duplex communication between server and clients. When something happened on the server side, clients are informed almost immediately. I had a lot of problems to implement web socket communication with PHP and Apache Server last year when I worked with that kind of project and don't know if anything is better right now. But, after reading some books for realtime applications development, I made it with [Pusher](http://pusher.com/), that's an commercial service but also have free plans.