# how to trigger notifications in mvc after something is saved in the database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, notifications, database-connection

how to trigger notifications in mvc after something is saved in the database?
e.g: if the Admin saves a new item in the database Employees are notified that there's a new item in stock.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use [polling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835835/jquery-simple-polling-example) to reflect any changes to your database or have [push notification](http://moderngeekdad.com/create-a-push-notification-system-with-signalr-and-toastr/) to notify client

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to generate some kind of notification or update to all your clients, then you should use `SIGNALR`
As of what I've come accross, it is one of the best solution to generate notifications to all clients across your application whenever there is any change in the DB.
Hope it satisfies your requirements