# Deferred in a while loop

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous, deferred

So I want to do a deferred ajax request in jquery until I receive a specific server response (non-null). How would I go about doing that?

```
while (data.response != null) {
  $.ajax(..).done(function(data);
}

function doUntilResult() {
    Server.doA().done(function(data) {
      Server.doB(data).done(function(result) {
          //if result == null, repeat again
      });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give a large measure of control, write `doUntilResult()` to accept :

- a `doThis` callback function, which determines what is to be done, and the re-try/terminate condition.
- an integer, which determines the delay between calls.

```
function doUntilResult(doThis, t) {
    function delay() {
        return $.Deferred(function(dfrd) {
            window.setTimeout(dfrd.resolve, t);
        });
    }
    function poll() {
        return $.when(doThis()).then(function(data) { // $.when() caters for non-async functions to be passed.
            return (data === null) ? delay().then(poll) : data; // continue on null, otherwise return data.
        });
    }
    return poll();
}
```

Now, you have a generalised `doUntilResult()` function, making it possible to change your mind about what is to be "done until" without re-writing. Everything is specified in the call (or calls).

For the original question, call as follows :

```
doUntilResult(function() {
    return $.ajax(..).then(function(data) {
        return data || null; // adjust as required to ensure that `null` is returned only for the "continue" condition.
    });
}, 1000); // 1 second delay between calls
```

For the edited question, call as follows :

```
doUntilResult(function() {
    return Server.doA().then(function(data) {
        return Server.doB(data);
    }).then(function(result) {
        return result || null; // adjust as required ...
    });
}, 1000); // 1 second delay between calls
```

Whatever you want to do, always ensure that the callback's .then chain terminates in a function that returns `null` whenever the poll is to continue.

[Here's a simple demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dmsm12uh/) which generates a random number from 0-10; numbers of 9 or greater are treated as data; under 9 will cause a re-try. (Monitor progress in console).

Answer (score 3):

You can't loop like this in Javascript.  Javascript is an event-driven system.  When you are looping like this, no other events can ever get processed.  As such, not even your first Ajax call will get processed.  In fact, you will probably just drive the JS engine into the ground by running out of some resource as the client tries to make millions of ajax calls all at once.

Instead, you can use the ajax result asynchronously and then decide from the result whether to call it again:

```
function poll() {
    $.ajax(...).then(function(data) {
        if (!data.xxxx) {
            // call it again after some short delay
            setTimeout(poll, 1000);
        } else {
            // got the result we wanted, process it
        }
    })
}

// start the polling
poll();
```

If you want the whole thing to return a promise, you can do this:

```
function delay(t) {
    return new $.Deferred(function(def) {
        setTimeout(def.resolve, t);
    }).promise();
}

function poll() {
    return $.ajax(...).then(function(data) {
        if (!data.xxxx) {
            // call it again after some short delay
            return delay(1000).then(poll);
        } else {
            // got the result we wanted, process it
            return someValue;
        }
    })
}

// start the polling
poll().then(function(result) {
    // process result here
});
```

P.S. It is pretty much never the right thing to just constantly poll some server as fast as you possibly can.  This might work fine if you only have a couple of users, but as soon as you have lots of users, all that will do is overwhelm your server with empty polling requests where most of the time, there's nothing to return to the client.  This is nightmare for handling load.  It's even better to find an architecture that is not polling, but if you are going to poll, then at least use some sort of timer to poll at some future time rather than as fast as possible.

P.P.S.  If you're really just waiting for some value to change on the server, then perhaps you should use a webSocket connection.  With that, the client establishes the connection to the server and the connection persists and then at any point in the future, the server can simply send a message to the client.  The client doesn't have to poll at all.  This can be massively more efficient on your server infrastructure and can deliver more timely results.

Comment: I'd like to use a deferred on this poll, is that possible? So that I can do poll().done(...) which of course would only be called when !data.xxx ?

Comment: @Wesley - I don't understand what you want.  There's `$.ajax(...).then()` in my answer which is using a promise already.  I prefer to use the ES6 standard `.then()` rather than the jQuery-specific `.done()`.  If you want the whole thing to return a promise when the polling is done, that can be done (though that isn't what you asked for in your question).

Comment: @Wesley - I added one more option.

Comment: also don't understand, you use a return in the callback, is that how then works? I only use .done which u always have to resolve or reject with the return value.

Comment: and one last question, my code above was not very detailed, i'm basically doing two requests in that "loop", see edited code; how would it work then because i'm working with multiple deferreds.

Comment: @Wesley - If you put your real code into your question (not this makeup pseudo code), then I can help you more specifically.  We can ALWAYS make better answers if you give us your real code.  I don't know why it is so many people think it's better to abstract their code and not post the real code.  That's simply not the case.  We can't make the best answer when you don't show us your real code.