# Check if new message was added AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to achieve sth like a facebook notifications '(1)' in the tab title.
Below is a simplified code of my future's site message box - what I want to do is to use AJAX to check if the new message was added (new tr), but without refreshing the site, and then show expected number in tab title.
Here is my code so far - but I have to refresh the site after adding a new table row...

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="tab">
            <table id="tabl">
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Message</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>John</td>
                    <td>Hey! What's up!</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>Kylie</td>
                    <td>Are you there Kylie?</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>Peter</td>
                    <td>Please, buy me a milk</td>
                </tr>                    
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var count = document.getElementById('tabl').rows.length - 1;
        var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var i = 0;
        x.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200) {
                document.title = '(' + count + ')' + ' ' + document.title;
            }
        };
        x.open('GET', 'http://localhost/php13/notif.php', true);
        x.send();
    </script>
</body>
```

How to achieve that without refreshing the site ?

Comment: IIRC that is called AJAX polling: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835835/jquery-simple-polling-example

Comment: Where are you getting any actual data in your AJAX request/response?

Comment: agree. No we have to use AJAX polling

Comment: @David - I dont know, I'm newbie to AJAX

Answer (score 1):

This is because for all practical purposes the `count` variable has a static value that is determined even before document load event or any AJAX calls happen. Your AJAX function does nothing to change the value of `count`, so every time that AJAX executes, you will set the `document.title` value to the same static value, with an ever-increasing number of `count` strong segments being added.

So let's say `count` is `4` on initial page load (as it would be in your example) and initial `document.title` value is `Test` here is how `document.title` value will change with each AJAX execution:

```
onload - Test
1st - (4) Test
2nd - (4) (4) Test
3rd - (4) (4) (4) Test
etc.
```

As you can see, your logic here is all wrong.

Comment: so how would you achieve that so 'count' wont be static ?

Comment: @Piter Depends on how the AJAX result comes back.  Youquestion says nothing about what you intendto happen in AJAX success handler.  Is it supposed to update table to a (potentially) different number of rows?  Does the AJAX response provide HTML DOM elements for insertion (in which case you may need to recount as you do at first) or does it provide a JSON or similar data structure that you need to use to update the DOM (in which case you might be able to derive the count from an array length or similar)?

Answer (score 1):

What back-end do you use? php? asp? node.js?

Anyway, I'm asuming someone actually types and sends that message, the absolutely best way to handle such a feature, is to execute it while the message is being sent. you must already know the recipient('s) of the message, so when it gets send, tell the recipient('s) to update their notifications.

I know you listed ajax, But using websockets is probably the best tech to achieve this, you don't need any constant loops to check the server for updates or any ajax polling, the server can simply just emit a message to the recipient without him having to do anything client-side, that a new message has been recieved.

Comment: I'm using php. I dont want to use websockets, just pure simple ajax

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement one of the technologies which would allow you to send messages **from server to client (browser)**.

It might be [Websockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket), [Server Sent Events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events) or [something else](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology).

Before you make a decision which technology to use you would need to think which legacy browser you want to support and check if this technology is supported. You could check it on [caniuse.com](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io).

You could also use a library like socket.io that would try to use newer technology (like Websockets) and if it's not supported by browser would fallback to the older solution.

If you write more about your backend it would be possible to give you more precise answer.

Comment: I dont want to use websockets, just pure simple ajax

Comment: So you have to poll server periodically. This is already covered by other answers.

Answer (score -2):

well easiest way is to use [setinterval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

```
<script>
setInterval(function(){ 
        var count = document.getElementById('tabl').rows.length - 1;
        var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var i = 0;
        x.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200) {
                document.title = '(' + count + ')' + ' ' + document.title;
            }
        };
        x.open('GET', 'http://localhost/php13/notif.php', true);
        x.send();
}, 1000);
    </script>
```

It's gonna check for new messages every 1 second

Comment: This is not proper way to call server periodically. If there are no messages came say for 1 hour you will request 3600 times for server.

Comment: yeah this is inefficient, but this is what the question was.

Comment: so what would you do @Akash Bhandwalkar ?

Comment: We have to use socket programming. I m Dan sure on this