# Send variable From PHP to AJAX

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a php page called posts.php, this page just `select all` from a database table named `posts` and display them. Down the page I have a textarea named `post`. When I press the submit button the AJAX script will send the text from textarea to a page called `insert.php`. This `insert.php` gets the submited text and insert it into `posts` table. How can I do this and how can I upload the `posts.php` when I have inserted a post into `posts` table.

**Example**:
User 123 writes a message in the textarea. He presses submit button. AJAX sends the post to `insert.php`. `Insert.php` inserts the post into `posts` tabel. `Posts.php` shows the message.

Comment: What I understand from your question is that you've a page with text input field and submit button and you need when user write down some value in the input field and press submit, the value should be placed in your posts table and also appear below your form. Am I right ?

Comment: You need to implement two ajax requests: one for inserting data (insert.php) and second for polling. More information on polling is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835835/jquery-simple-pollingexample)

Comment: There are 2 ways to achieve this. a) Create an AJAX call which can reload the posts on the page. After AJAX call for insert, call the post refresh AJAX call. b) Refresh the page when you call insert.php

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the following article on how to ask a question on this site: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it very easily! Here's a **very simple** example.

**func.js**

```
$(document).on("click", ".submitBtn", function() {
    var textareaVal = $(".textarea").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "insert.php",
        dataType: "text",
        data: { postVar: textareaVal },
        success: function(data) {
            $(".resultDiv").load("posts.php");
        }
    });
});
```

**insert.php**

```
// You have to pay attention to AJAX can only invite your file!
if (!empty($_SERVER["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"]) && strtolower($_SERVER["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"]) == "xmlhttprequest") {
    if (isset($_POST["postVar"])) {
        $var = sanitize($_POST["postVar"]); // You need sanitize the data!
        // Insert into your table...
    }
}
```

In your **posts.php**, SELECT datas from your table, but only select the data, without „HTML container”! Your JS file load this datas on your resultDiv box.

Comment: look at my answer please!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain why you would need to do this  via ajax, but:

```
$( "#myForm" ).submit(function( event ) {
 $.ajax({
         type: 'post',
         url: '../insert.php' ,
         data: { value1: document.getElementById('textarea').value },
         success: function () {
           alert("yay!");
         }
 });
});
```