# database updation check in background

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax

I am working on a tic-tac-toe game which two gamers can play simultaneously, after every click I have to update the database but my problem is that how the other gamer will know that next player has clicked a box and updated the database without page refresh because that will take a long time?

Comment: please include code

Answer (score 2):

There are a few options.

1) Use AJAX polling every so often.  A simple example taken from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835835/jquery-simple-polling-example) and modified:

```
function doPoll(){
    $.post('endpoint(url or page)', function(data) {
        // process results here
        setTimeout(doPoll,5000);
    });
}
```

2) Look at web sockets. This post has a good overview:  [In what situations would AJAX long/short polling be preferred over HTML5 WebSockets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028770/in-what-situations-would-ajax-long-short-polling-be-preferred-over-html5-websock)

3) Take a [look at SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr); from the website:

> ASP.NET SignalR is a new library for ASP.NET developers that makes
>   developing real-time web functionality easy. SignalR allows
>   bi-directional communication between server and client. Servers can
>   now push content to connected clients instantly as it becomes
>   available. SignalR supports Web Sockets, and falls back to other
>   compatible techniques for older browsers. SignalR includes APIs for
>   connection management (for instance, connect and disconnect events),
>   grouping connections, and authorization.

This was also a [nice overview of several options](http://dsheiko.com/weblog/websockets-vs-sse-vs-long-polling).