# how to proceed further with this API

Tags: javascript, api

To brush up on my web development skills I am trying to re-learn API. I got the from this website:
https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/10808728/SzS8rjbc?version=latest

In my JS file, I have the following code:

```
var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("https://api.covid19api.com/summary", requestOptions)

  .then(response => response.text())

  .then(result => console.log(result))

  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

And I see that it logs a lot of data, but I'm not sure how to grab a specific data from the API and display it on the HTML page.

I tried something like this in the JS file:

```
var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("https://api.covid19api.com/summary", requestOptions)

  .then(response => response.text())

  .then(result => console.log(result))

  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));

let tdeaths = data.global.TotalDeaths;

document.getElementById('tdeaths').innerHTML = tdeaths.toLocaleString('en');
```

But nothing is showing up on my HTML file with

Comment: Are you importing this JS in your HTML?

Comment: I am yes,   <script src="resources/js/testing.js"></script>

Comment: Because I see the console.log stuff when I open up the HTML page on Chrome

Answer (score 0):

you have to put your code in the `.then` statement. So it should look like this:

```
fetch("https://api.covid19api.com/summary", requestOptions)

  .then(response => response.json())

  .then(result => {
   let tdeaths = result.global.TotalDeaths;
   document.getElementById('tdeaths').innerHTML = tdeaths.toLocaleString('en');
   })

  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Answer (score 0):

I see there are two problems.
1. How are you updating `data.global.TotalDeaths`? it will take the initial value because tdeaths is not getting output from response.
2. The `document.getElementByid` statement would run before it retrives values from API. so after fixing 1st issue, you should put the statement like below(considering result = data)

```
.then(result => {
     let tdeaths = result.global.TotalDeaths;
     document.getElementById('tdeaths').innerHTML = tdeaths.toLocaleString('en');
  })
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked, I'm not sure about question 1? I think you mean how do I have a system of it updating numbers lets say every minute? I don't think I have it yet. How would I do that?

Comment: You can set polling the API using this setInterval. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835835/jquery-simple-polling-example

Comment: I'm assuming instead of "ajax/test.html" I would replace it with the name of my HTML file, which is index.html, and that this would go on the bottom of the JS page?