# Flask - Refresh data via Ajax when a function is called

Tags: ajax, flask

I have a function, which renders my template when called:

```
def exampleTemplate():
    exampleData = getData()
    render_template(index.html, data=exampleData)
```

And I have something like an API, which is called from other sites. It manipulates the exampleData in exampleTemplate.

```
def exampleAPI():
    manipulateExampleData()
    return json()
```

How do I refresh the data with Ajax in exampleTemplate whenever the exampleData is manipulated via exampleAPI()?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to refresh as soon as `exampleAPI` is called you will need to use sockets, so you can send data from the server to the browser without the browser asking for it. Check out [flask-socketio](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

If you don't want to deal with sockets you can use polling, where you make an ajax request to a new route that gives you `exampleData` every few seconds or so. Then you can replace the data in your html with the new `exampleData`. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835835/jquery-simple-polling-example) for details on how to do that with jQuery.